# How to fix it this error : InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I could not find a solution with other errors like this on. I get this error:
**Exception :**

```
10-28 09:47:35.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7884): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
10-28 10:04:25.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9471):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-28 10:04:25.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9471):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-28 10:04:25.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9471):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-28 10:04:25.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9471):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-28 10:04:25.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9471):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

I try last 4 days but could not found any solution. Please help me.

Please find the my code in below

Thank you :)

**XML :-**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <com.mst.app.adapter.TransparentPanel
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bar_gradient"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hide_popup_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/listview_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="  Close  "
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Offers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Offers"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="Testing offers \n"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </com.mst.app.adapter.TransparentPanel>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Code :-**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabMapMainFragmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**TabMapMainFragmentActivity.java**

```
package com.mst.app.view;

import com.mst.app.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class TabMapMainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    TabMapAllFoodTypeFragment tab1;
    TabMapVegFoodTypeFragment tab2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_main_fragment);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // adding tabs
        Tab aTab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        aTab1.setText("All");
        aTab1.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(aTab1);

        Tab aTab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        aTab2.setText("Veg");
        aTab2.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(aTab2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
        if (selectedTabIndex == 0) 
        {
            tab1 = new TabMapAllFoodTypeFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.tabPlaceHolderInvoices, tab1);
        }
        else if (selectedTabIndex == 1) 
        {
            tab2 = new TabMapVegFoodTypeFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.tabPlaceHolderInvoices, tab2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**TabMapAllFoodTypeFragment.java**

```
package com.mst.app.view;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mst.app.R;

public class TabMapAllFoodTypeFragment extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }




}
```

**TabMapVegFoodTypeFragment.java**

```
package com.mst.app.view;

import com.mst.app.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabMapVegFoodTypeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_only, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mst.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mst.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mst.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/restaurant"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mst.app.view.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mst.app.view.MapActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mst.app.view.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mst.app.view.TabMapMainFragmentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try change fragment to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
```

Is not correct. Instead of `class`, you have to use `android:name`. So the correct one would be:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
```

And make sure that you have added the Google Maps dependency in your `build.gradle`

Comment: I did it. same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your inflating a Fragment to inside of another fragment. This called Nested Fragments. And Its implementation little bit different than regular one. You can use MapView for your map.

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
```

instead of

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
```

Then basicly findView this id and call .getMap() to get GoogleMap object. All of them are same after this.

Comment: after change mapview i got new error 10-28 14:19:16.286: E/AndroidRuntime(7611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mst.app/com.mst.app.view.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException